# using jquery address with angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, migration, jquery-address

Is it possible to use jquery address plugin to handle the SPA and use angularjs to load/bind the content of pages? I want to migrate my web app which is SPA, but its using jquery address. I cannot convert the whole web app to angular based quickly so I need to convert a couple of pages to angular in each build. Can someone guide me or propose some solution here?

Comment: what problems are you having? should be doable.

Comment: On angularjs we can get the required objects before the route finished loading. How we will handle it when pages are being requested via address plugin?